# Can't get Navigation bar customized after the first screen.

Tags: ios, swift

My home screen looks exactly like I want it to but the next screen just has the back button up there despite having run the same code. Here is the code I am running in the initial view controllers view did load method.

```
    let nav = self.navigationController?.navigationBar
    nav?.barStyle = UIBarStyle.Black
    nav?.tintColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
    let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height:40))
    imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
    let image = UIImage(named: "NavBarPhoto")
    imageView.image = image
    navigationItem.titleView = imageView
```

Comment: the navigation item is different from one view controller to another in the navigation controller, did the tint color change ?

Comment: No, the image goes away but the tint appears to be the same.

Answer (score 0):

the solution is to make one root view controller where you customize your navigation bar in the `viewDidLoad`.

Then all your view controllers should inherit for it.

Comment: Thats exactly what I'm doing, but picture is gone on the next screen.

Comment: the next screen's view controller is inheriting from the view controller where you do the custom navigation bar ?

Comment: Yes. All I get it the back button on the bar, no custom image.

Answer (score 0):

When creating the folder for the ViewController Class that was giving me trouble I accidentally just pressed enter and let Xcode name the file, well, simply file. I quickly corrected the problem, thinking that it would have no other affect. Subsequently, while running my app I left getting Unknown class PickingViewController in Interface Builder file. I suspected that all these issues were tied together and they were. I clicked on the troublesome view, added him to the current module, now on to the next problem. Thanks guys for the comments.